# Python Pulp - Output Variable Matrix Solution to Excel

Tags: python, optimization, pulp

I am trying to output the solution of one of the array variables into an excel workbook.  I am not able to get anything other than the representation of the variables within PULP as opposed to the solved value (which is what I am after).

I have tried a number of different pandas/numpy data frames and arrays but no success.  Tried using the excel writer library as well but no dice.

```
YPER = 30
HE = 24

yearlyhours = []
yearlyhours = [(i,j) for i in range(YPER) for j in range(HE)]

MAHLDIFF = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("MAHLDIFF", (range(YPER), range(HE)), lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')

MAHLDIFFOUTPUT = []
for i,j in yearlyhours:
    var_output = {'MAHLDIFF':MAHLDIFF[i][j]}
    MAHLDIFFOUTPUT.append(var_output)
dfOptResults = pd.DataFrame.from_records(MAHLDIFFOUTPUT)
dfOptResults.to_excel('file.xls')
```

This is the output I get so far, just a sample of full array:

```
    MAHLDIFF
0   MAHLDIFF_0_0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really about exporting to Excel, it's just a general question about how to access the values of the variables in PuLP. To do so, use `<var_name>.value()`, e.g., `MAHLDIFF[i][j].value()`.

You can also loop through all variables in the model using, e.g.:

```
for v in prob.variables():
    print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
```

where `prob` is the Python variable that holds your PuLP model.

Comment: Larry, you are absolutely right!  I appreciate the scoping check for the question.  Either way, this obtained exactly the values that I needed.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: Just in case you read this, maybe you could help with one more thing.  The output top excel is in a single columnar format.  I need it to be based on the array specified in YPER and HE.  Takes the 6x5 matrix and outputs as a single column of 0-29 values.  I would like it to be 0-5 in column A, 6-10 in B, etc, etc.  Any ideas?  Using the same code above just added the .value()

Comment: That's a Python question, not really a PuLP question. Either way, you should post it as a new question. (I'm not the guy to help with that one.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about https://solverstudio.org/. If you want to use Excel to manage your data.